# get `top` output for non-interactive shell

Tags: scripting, top

I want to implement top function for a web app. Is it possible to get the output of the `top` command in non-interactive shell?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`top -b -n 1`

From `man top`:

> ```
>   -b : Batch mode operation
>         Starts top in 'Batch mode', which could be useful for 
>         sending output from  top  to other programs  or  to  
>         a file.  In this mode, top will not accept input and runs
>         until the iterations limit you've set with the '-n' 
>         command-line option  or  until killed.
> ```

Comment: so if i want to add a column in non interactive mode. say i want to add swap usage by process how do i do that ? usually in interactive mode this is what i do  : shift + f ----> press p ---> hit enter.

Comment: For completeness, answering Sagar's question: When running top in interactive mode you can choose columns and orderings, then press "W" to save $HOME/.toprc . This file will be read in next calls to "top", be interactive or not. Simply remove that file to return to defaults. Regards, /Angel